# Ubuntu - Moduli file upgrade story

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, ssh, openssh

SSH uses `/etc/ssh/moduli` file for DH exchange key alogithm. Only root has write permissions to modify the `/etc/ssh/moduli` file.

Assume that we modify the `/etc/ssh/moduli` file for some reason (Ex - removing prime numbers less than 2048 bits or add new prime numbers to moduli file).

What happens when I upgrade my Ubuntu to a new version (14.04 to 16.04)?
Does the moduli file gets overwritten (or) changed?